# Caching of static contets of the SmartGWT app

Tags: caching, https, jsonp, smartgwt, same-origin-policy

I'm developing app with SmartGWT framework which gonna work through ssl-connection. SmartGwt libs are big enough, and using of https prevents caching.
Is there any way to use JSONP to access static content of SmartGwt app via http? 
Or maybe you can suggest any other way of static content caching in this case?

Thanks

Comment: I also have the same problem. Smartgwt works fine on http, but doesn't run on https. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, persistent caching is possible with HTTPS requests by setting the response headers appropriately:

- **Cache-Control** to **Public** (Read [here](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/01/15/https-performance-tuning/), tip #3)
- **Expires** to a [far future expire](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-expires.html)